# Was Mona 'the vampire' delusional or just day-dreaming?

Tags: mona-the-vampire

I remember having a strong negative reaction to how the primary character's day dreams are portrayed in the TV Series.

> The series follows the adventures of Mona Parker, who refers to herself as "Mona the Vampire", as well as her two best friends, Lily Duncan ("Princess Giant") and Charley Bones ("Zapman"), and her pet cat, Fang, as they imagine themselves confronting a new supernatural foe, or solving a supernatural mystery, in every episode, but there are always rational explanations for what they see.
>
> <sub>[Wikipedia, *Mona the Vampire*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mona_the_Vampire)</sub>

I distinctly remember that Mona is portrayed as strongly believing the day dreams to be true, to the extent that she would put others in harm's way to keep up this delusion... for instance I vaguely recall at least one instance where she tried to get someone fired.

She also seemed to be genuinely distressed that none of the adults believed her when they were forced to confront her day dreams.

**In the TV Series, does Mona ever acknowledge that she is daydreaming?** (For instance, going back on her delusions as imaginations rather than just mistakes she has made in the same delusional reality.)

Answer (score 6):

"Delusional" feels like a harsh word - I always interpreted her as merely having an overactive imagination, similar to Calvin from *Calvin and Hobbes* - but based on how the series' episodes tended to play out, it's likely that her belief in the supernatural is being reinforced by a positive feedback loop. Generally, while Mona is wrong about the supernatural nature of the mysteries she investigates, she *is* correct about who or what is at fault, seemingly validating the original theory.

As an example, the episode I remember most clearly is one in which the arrival of a new pair of lunch assistants at Mona's school correlates with a spate of food poisonings. Mona correctly deduces that the two are linked, and that the lunch assistants are at fault, but then jumps to the conclusion that they're evil shapeshifting salmonella monsters. The episode ends with them being arrested and it's revealed that they really just had poor hygiene standards, but in Mona's mind, if she was right about them being behind the food poisonings, then she must have been right about them being salmonella monsters too, right? And so the "delusion" intensifies.

The closest thing I can remember to an acknowledgement that it's all make-believe is a flashback episode showing how Lily first became friends with Mona. After showing Lily her "Mona the Vampire" alter-ego, Mona offers to help Lily come up with one, and comes up with the "Princess Giant" outfit and moniker more or less on the spot.

Comment: The episode was called [The Sam'n Ella Infiltration](https://monathevampire.fandom.com/wiki/The_Sam%27n_Ella_Infiltration).  I found the names particularly memorable.

Answer (score 2):

No, she never admitted it was all daydreaming. I think she has Delusional disorder which basically means she thinks everything was real. People with this disorder can't tell reality from delusion and generally possess an almost stubborn belief that what they think is real is reality. It’s actually kind of sad that her parents aren’t getting treated for that because as she grows up it’ll become a serious problem.

Comment: Hi and welcome! Have you taken the [tour]? This is a good answer, but it could be even better if you could reference an episode that backs up your conclusion